# How to Mathematically Represent the R.L. Graham Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, notation

I am aware the convex hull algorithm known as [Graham Scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan) can be computed by sorting the derived vectors from points given in a 2D plane. One then iterates through a series of Cross Product calculations to find the determinant of a pair of vectors derived from the sequence of given points. This determine whether to move clockwise of counter clockwise with respect to drawing a convex hull in an efficient manner.

How do I represent that using sigma notation?

I was thinking along the line of:
$\sum_{i=1}^{N} Det(V_i,V_{i+1})...Det(V_n,V_{n-1}),$
where $V_i$ is the initial vector.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there something wrong with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [paper](http://www.utdallas.edu/~daescu/convexhull.pdf), it looks like what I had above is the best way to represent Graham Scan:
$\sum_{i=1}^{N} Det(V_i,V_{i+1})...Det(V_n,V_{n-1}),$
where $V_i$ is the initial vector.